# apply css with name of element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an element under:

> form > section > div( it has dataTables_length class) > label with name attribute.

I want to apply my css to this label. How can I do this ?

*Note: my select element created in runtime cant see on code*

Here is my label attribute

```
form div.dataTables_length label{
/*border-top-color:#ffffff;*/
    border: 0px;
color:#444444;
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #ffffff;
background: none;
/*background:#f1f1f1;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f1f1f1',  
                   endColorstr='#e8e8e8');
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f1f1f1), 
    to(#e8e8e8));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f1,  #e8e8e8);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f1,  #e8e8e8);*/
}
```

and my css I think should be work but not:

```
form div.dataTables_length label input[name^="sonuclar_length"] {    
margin-top:-15px;
background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML. You want to apply CSS to your LABEL, so why are you trying to add it to the input inside a label?

Comment: Do you have input inside the label or BESIDES the label

Comment: No one can help you in this case unless and until you don't show your HTML here. Or can you make a fiddle for it.

Comment: @Y3N3RRR : HTML markup is important, please provide that or label class!!

Comment: I just solved issue but u right I must have sent html. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply css to the label, then

```
form div.dataTables_length label[name='somename'] {
    color: red;
}
```

should work.

but you have applied the css to the input tag inside label (guessing as per your css).